# On particular sumset properties of permanent?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, matrices, sumsets, permanent

Denote $\mathcal R_2[n]=\mathcal R[n] + \mathcal R[n]$ to be sumset of integers in $\mathcal R[n]$ where $\mathcal R[n]$ to be set of permanents possible with permanents of $n\times n$ matrices with $0/1$ entries.

We have:

$$\mathcal R_2[1]=\mathcal R[1]+\mathcal R[1]=\{0,1\}+\{0,1\}=\{0,1,2\}\subseteq\mathcal R[2]$$

$$\mathcal R_2[2]=\mathcal R[2]+\mathcal R[2]=\{0,1,2\}+\{0,1,2\}=\{0,1,2,3,4\}\subseteq\mathcal R[3]$$

$$\mathcal R_2[3]=\mathcal R[3]+\mathcal R[3]=\{0,1,2,3,4,6\}+\{0,1,2,3,4,6\}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12\}\subseteq\mathcal R[4]$$

However $\mathcal R_2[n]\not\subseteq\mathcal R[n+1]$?

Counter example: $27,35\in\mathcal R_2[4]\cap \mathcal R[5]^c$. Also check OEIS A089477.

Denote $R_2'[n]=\{i\in\mathcal R_2[n]:i\in\mathcal R[n+1]\}$.

> 1. Is there an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(2-\epsilon)|R_2'[n]|>|R_2[n]|$ holds for all $n$ bigger than some $n_0\in\Bbb N$?
> 2. If there is no $\epsilon>0$ then what is the slowest growing function $f(n)$ such that $f(n)|R_2'[n]|>|R_2[n]|$ holds for all $n$ bigger than some $n_0\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Your question 2 is malformed. Decide on whether script T is a set or a number, and use it consistently.  If you consider the subsets which are nonzero mod (k!), and show that they enjoy sufficient properties (all odd numbers below the largest odd are also part of the range, for example), then the result should follow from these sufficient properties.  Gerhard "Do Not Overload Your Notation" Paseman, 2017.11.15.

Comment: "..then the result should follow from these sufficient properties" sounds interesting. Can you post what you know?

Comment: I just did.  As a guide show (if it can be done) that any positive odd number j less than the largest odd number k in the range for n is also in the range for n.  However, if this fails, there may still be a positive answer to the first question.  Gerhard "Intervals Are Easier To Understand" Paseman, 2017.11.15.

Comment: For 1: Seems a little unlikely, as it feels like saying that $pc(f),pc(g) \leq n$ implies $pc(f+g) \leq n+1$ (where pc=permanental complexity), whereas it's probably close to tight that $pc(f+g) \leq 2n+1$... What's the crucial difference between that and the 0-1 setting that would allow your Q1 to have a positive answer? Have you tried computer experiments, even to check if $R_2(4) \subseteq R(5)$, for example?

Comment: I think it is simpler in that just the range is being talked about. It holds when one adds two small values and when one adds two large values in the range for n.  It would be interesting to see if for (large) n+1 that there is a permanent value of 7 + n!  I am guessing that it is simpler, as I don't know about permanental complexity.  Gerhard "Also Unsure Of Determinantal Complexity" Paseman, 2017.11.15.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow "..whereas it's probably close to tight that pc(f+g)≤2n+1" what evidence do we have?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow How is this connected to pc?

Comment: @Turbo: Evidence for 2n+1: if we replace pc with formula size $F$, surely there are $f,g$ s.t. $F(f+g) = F(f) + F(g) + 1$ - probably random functions should work. Connection between your Q and pc: We could define "pc" of a number as $pc(n) = \min \{m : \exists A \in \{0,1\}^{m \times m} perm(A) = n\}$, and then your question is precisely "If $pc(a),pc(b) \leq n$, does that imply $pc(a+b) \leq n+1$?" Obviously formulas and integers are different, but there's still some connection; e.g., there is an analogue of circuit complexity for integers, e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1704).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow 1. assume what you say is false and we need n+c (at a c>0) matrix size for representing sum of pairs of all integers represented by n x n matrix with 0/1. Does it give VNP=VP or something non-trivial?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow 2. assume what you say is true and we need 2n+1 matrix size for representing sum of pairs of all integers represented by n x n matrix with 0/1. Does it give VNP=VP or something non-trivial if we can represent at least 1/n^c (at a c>0) of all pair sums of nxn matrix permanents of 0/1 type (randomized self reduction)?

Comment: Because of the relationship between pc and formula size, your questions seem related to the tau-complexity studied by [Burgisser]( https://doi.org/10.1007/s00037-009-0260-x), who showed that if $n!$ can be computed by formulas of size $poly(log n)$ whose only inputs are 1, then VP=VNP. If you solve them I'll be very interested to hear about it.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow  1. I am not sure how it relates to n!. We still need permanent of size O(n) to get n! even if pc of a+b was n+1. 2. Abstract of paper says "We prove that if there are arithmetic circuits of size polynomial in n for computing the permanent of n by n matrices, then τ(n!) is polynomially bounded in log n" (which seems to me vp=vnp implies tau(n!) is polylog n and not other way around).

3. Can you fully explain the implication in answer if we get $n+c$ or $1.0000000001n+c$ for some fixed $c>0$ for at least 1/p(n) fraction of all pair sums (for some subexponential function p(n))?

Comment: @Turbo: My point wasn't that you could use Burgisser's result about n! directly, but that perhaps his technique would let you answer your questions 1/2 from the comments.

Comment: @Turbo: In the latest revision of your question, incorporating my answer, it should be $27, 35 \in \mathcal{R}_2[4] \cap \mathcal{R}[5]^c$ rather than 27 and 29, since 29 is in both $\mathcal{R}_2[4]$ and $\mathcal{R}[5]$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the conjecture is false.  Following up on Grochow's recommendation, *Mathematica* computations show
$$\mathcal{R}[4] = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 18, 24 \}$$
so that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}_2[4] = \{&0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, \\&22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 42, 48 \}.\end{align}
But (after some hours)
\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}[5] = \{&0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, \\&22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, \\&46, 48, 50, 53, 54, 60, 64, 72, 78, 96, 120\}. \end{align}
In particular, $27, 35 \in \mathcal{R}_2[4]$ but neither is in $\mathcal{R}[5]$.

Concerning the sufficient condition $\{0,1,2,\dots,2(n!)\} \subseteq \mathcal{R}[n+1]$, note that 27, 35, 37, 41, 43, 45, 47 are all missing from $\mathcal{R}[5]$.

*Mathematica* code for $\mathcal{R}[5]$:

Union[Table[
  Permanent[Partition[IntegerDigits[i, 2, 25], 5]], {i, 0, 2^25 - 1}]]

Comment: That 27 is not in R[5] (and 29 is) is very surprising to me.  Can anyone else verify this?  Gerhard "Making Permanent Spectrum More Mysterious" Paseman, 2017.11.16.

Comment: Indeed OEIS A089477 confirms 27 is missing. Does someone have a binary 5x5 matrix with permanent of 29?  Gerhard "Can It Be Symmetric Too?" Paseman, 2017.11.16.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has permanent 29 (and is symmetric too).

Comment: Thank you @Brian.  It would be nice to have a combinatorial (non-exhaustive) proof that 27 is not in R[5]. Gerhard "Doesn't Ask For Much, Mostly" Paseman, 2017.11.17.